# Applying same function to every element in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, closest-points

Say I need to find the euclidean distance from one (x,y) coordinate to every coordinate in an array of million coordinates and then select the coordinate with the smallest distance.

At present I loop though the million element array, calculate distance keeping track of the minimum. Is there a way I could do it differently and faster.

Thanks

Comment: Do you take the square root in the distance calculation? You don't need that for finding the closest point.

Comment: Show us the math you're using to calculate distance. Maybe that can be optimized.

Comment: if abs(a) < abs (b) then sqrt(abs(a))<sqrt(abs(b))

Comment: Have you tried OpenMP?  Is it floats or doubles?  If floats, you could offload it to the graphics card.

Comment: @pmg no I don't take the square root. Thanks anyway

Comment: @LipikaDeka; Is the point x,y is fixed?

Comment: This is embarrassingly parallelizable, so although you can't really reduce the number of computations, you can reduce the elapsed time if you have lots of cores (or access to something like CUDA or even SIMD)

Comment: @haccks, No (x,y) is not fixed and I have to repeat this operation with many (x,y) pairs

Comment: @LipikaDeka Then edit the question accordingly. A good answer is getting downvoted unnecessarily.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay - repeatedly calling `closest(point, set)` with different points still isn't the same as calling `closest_pair(set)`.

Comment: @Useless I know. But the answer is closer to the question with a very optimal solution.

Comment: It seems to be a very optimal solution to a _different problem_ though. Unless I've also misunderstood the OP, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve your algorithm significantly by using a more complex data structure for instance a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). Still if what you expect to do is to simply search once for the nearest neighbour, you can not possibly perform better than iterating over all points.

What you **can** do, though is optimize the function that computes the distance and also(as mentioned in comments) you may omit the square root as comparing the squares of two non-negative integers is just the same as comparing the values.

Comment: You could terminate early, if the points were organised in cache friendly blocks in memory depending on rough position in the plane, each square with height & width of length n.  Now if the block containing the point and those adjacent are scanned first, the closest point is likely to be at distance <= sqrt( sqr(dx) + sqr(dy)) less than distance across 2 blocks in 1 dimension, in which case no more blocks need iterating over, as the far blocks will have a dx + dy > sqr( min distance).  You may use Manhatten distances, to choose blocks, knowing further ones cannot contain nearer points

Comment: @Rob11311 this would work but it implies additional constraint on the input.

Comment: I just don't believe that you read in a million points, and then are only interested in the nearest to 1 single one.. normally if you want one, you want to do it again, so think organising data is usually a win

Comment: If that is the case k-d tree will help

Comment: Looks like it's dividing the space up.. just wonder how expensive it is to create and traverse, compared to a less exact, less elegant, crude Monte-carlo style distribution method which parcels out the space into "tiles".

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from the question is that you wanna find closest pair of point. There is an algorithm [Closest pair of points problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) to solve this.

[image]

Closest Pair of a set of points:

> - Divide the set into two equal sized parts by the line `l`, and recursively compute the minimal distance in each part.
> - Let `d` be the minimal of the two minimal distances.
> - Eliminate points that lie farther than d apart from `l`
> - Sort the remaining points according to their y-coordinates
> - Scan the remaining points in the y order and compute the distances of each point to its five neighbors.
> - If any of these distances is less than `d` then update `d`.

The whole of algorithm Closest Pair takes `O(logn*nlogn)` = `O(nlog`<sup>`2`</sup>`n)` time.

We can improve on this algorithm slightly by reducing the time it takes to achieve the y-coordinate sorting in Step 4. This is done by asking that the recursive solution computed in Step 1 returns the points in sorted order by their y coordinates. This will yield two sorted lists of points which need only be merged (a linear time operation) in Step 4 in order to yield a complete sorted list. Hence the revised algorithm involves making the following changes:

> - Step 1: Divide the set into..., and recursively compute the distance in each part, returning the points in each set in sorted order by y-coordinate.
> - Step 4: Merge the two sorted lists into one sorted list in `O(n)` time.

Hence the merging process is now **dominated by the linear time** steps thereby yielding an `O(nlogn)` algorithm for finding the closest pair of a set of points in the plane.

Comment: @haccks but OP searches for the point closest to a given input point which is a different problem.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev; He want to select the co-ordinate with minimum distance.

Comment: `I need to find the euclidean distance from one (x,y) coordinate to every coordinate in an array` maybe I missinterpret this but it seems to me OP has these `x` and `y` fixed. Still I don't understand the down votes  answer is correct for a given interpretation of the question

Comment: Isn't this the closest pair of points in the set, rather than the closest point (singular) in the set to some other given point?

Answer (score 1):

You could save quite a chunk of time by first checking if both the distance along x and along y are <= than the last distance (squared) you stored. If it's true, then you carry on with calculating the distance (squared). Of course the amount of time you save depends on how the points are distributed.

Comment: no, don't add  branching there, it will be way way slower than just doing the 5 instruction calculation